# C adding array elements cause segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, exec

I have read several forums but can't find the solution to this.

```
int sIndex = 3;
char serverArgs[serverCommandCount + 3][20];


strcpy(serverArgs[0], "ant");
strcpy(serverArgs[1], "-f");
strcpy(serverArgs[2], "/dev/server1/trunk/build.xml");
if(serverStop){strcpy(serverArgs[sIndex], "jboss-stop"); sIndex++;}
if(serverClean){strcpy(serverArgs[sIndex], "clean"); sIndex++;}
if(serverDeploy){strcpy(serverArgs[sIndex], "deploy"); sIndex++;}
if(releaseDB){strcpy(serverArgs[sIndex], "releasedb"); sIndex++;}
if(createDB){strcpy(serverArgs[sIndex], "createdb"); sIndex++;}
if(serverStart){strcpy(serverArgs[sIndex], "jboss-start"); sIndex++;}
if(serverDebug){strcpy(serverArgs[sIndex], "jboss-start-debug"); sIndex++;}

execv(antEx, serverArgs);
```

In this solution the problem is the execv wanting a char *[ ] rather than a char[ ].

```
int sIndex = 3;
char *serverArgs[serverCommandCount + 3];

for(index = 0; index < serverCommandCount + 3; index++)
    serverArgs[index] = malloc(20);
strcpy(serverArgs[0], "ant");
strcpy(serverArgs[1], "-f");
strcpy(serverArgs[2], "/dev/server1/trunk/build.xml");
if(serverStop){strcpy(serverArgs[sIndex], "jboss-stop"); sIndex++;}
if(serverClean){strcpy(serverArgs[sIndex], "clean"); sIndex++;}
if(serverDeploy){strcpy(serverArgs[sIndex], "deploy"); sIndex++;}
if(releaseDB){strcpy(serverArgs[sIndex], "releasedb"); sIndex++;}
if(createDB){strcpy(serverArgs[sIndex], "createdb"); sIndex++;}
if(serverStart){strcpy(serverArgs[sIndex], "jboss-start"); sIndex++;}
if(serverDebug){strcpy(serverArgs[sIndex], "jboss-start-debug"); sIndex++;}

execv(antEx, serverArgs);
```

When I try it this way, I get a segmentation fault when it tries to execute

strcpy(serverArgs[1], "-f");

What am I missing?

Comment: I have also tried this without the malloc.

Comment: The line `strcpy(serverArgs[2], "/dev/server1/trunk/build.xml");` is probably no good -- that string is larger than twenty characters.

Comment: @Peter You should add that as an answer (instead of a comment on the question).

Comment: Another thing to note: use of `strcpy` is generally frowned upon, for exactly this reason – it's much too easy to create buffer overflows. Use `strncpy` and provide an explicit length instead.

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers, `strncpy` is probably more "frowned upon" than `strcpy`, because you have to watch that the result is always nul terminated.

Comment: I have tried strncpy and it didnt work. Also, the program doesn't even make it to strcpy(serverArgs[2], "/dev/server1/trunk/build.xml") before it crashes so it can't be that. it crashes when executing strcpy(serverArgs[1],....)

Comment: @JensGustedt I agree that it's problematic in its own way, but I'd hardly say that it's _worse_ than `strcpy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the man page for `execv`:

> The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer.

Comment: Ok, but I dont think i can even get that far because it crashes when adding the second element. This is my goal:

char *serverArgs[] = {"ant", "-f", "/dev/server1/trunk/build.xml", "solr-stop", "solr-start",(char*) 0};

but i need to determine which/how many options to include.

Comment: Given the code we see, it doesn't make sense that it crashes at that line, except if `malloc` returned `NULL`. One should always check for that anyway, but in this case, even more so. Add the `NULL` check, adjust your `malloc`ed size for the long string, make your array one longer for the terminating `NULL` and try again. If it still crashes, we need more code, because that ought to be impossible then.

Comment: Ok, here's where I'm at now:

<code>
    int sIndex = 3;
  char *serverArgs[serverCommandCount + 4];

        for(index = 0; index < serverCommandCount + 4; index++)
            serverArgs[index] = malloc(100);
    ...

    execv(antEx, serverArgs);
</code>

Now it makes it to the execv() command but crashes there. Here is the message I get when I compile:

warning: passing argument 2 of 'execv' from incompatible pointer type

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot the null on the end. it works now, thanks!

Comment: Let the loop run only for `index < serverCommandCount + 3`, since the last pointer should be `NULL`. Don't forget to set `serverArgs[sIndex] = NULL` after the copying loop (free unused allocated storage before that). The incompatible pointer type should be because `execv` expects a `char *const argv[]`, that shouldn't cause a crash.

Answer (score 2):

Turning my comment into an answer: The line strcpy(serverArgs[2], "/dev/server1/trunk/build.xml"); is probably no good -- that string is larger than twenty characters. You should be completely sure that you `malloc` enough space for everything that could possibly go into the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd solution is generally the good one, but if you have it on your platform, use `strdup` instead of `malloc` and `strcpy` to allocate and copy the strings in one go. If you don't have `strdup`, it would not be very difficult to write one yourself.

Also, for that you don't have a surprise for your string array, do:

```
char *serverArgs[serverCommandCount + 3] = { 0 };
```

to initialize all the pointers correctly.

Comment: I don't really understand how strdup would work in this circumstance, will you give me an example?

Comment: You would use something like `serverArgs[i] = strndup("foo bar baz mumble pies", 19);`. This copies the "foo..." string up to 19 characters (the size of the buffer minus one null character at the end), and puts it into the array. Try `man strdup`.

Comment: "the size of the buffer minus one null character" -- there is no buffer here (the malloc loop can/should be omitted). strdup, not strndup, is the correct function to use here. There are rare use cases for strndup, but this isn't one of them.